# sum rows based on unique columns awk

Tags: awk, count, unique

I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this (for more than >100 columns):

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$4}{b[$1]+=$5}{c[$1]+=$6}{d[$1]+=$7}{e[$1]+=$8}{f[$1]+=$9}{g[$1]+=$10}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i],b[i],c[i],d[i],e[i],f[i],g[i]}'
```

Here is the input:

```
 a1 1   1   2   2
 a2 2   5   3   7
 a2 2   3   3   8
 a3 1   4   6   1
 a3 1   7   9   4
 a3 1   2   4   2
```

and output:

```
 a1 1 1 2 2
 a2 4 8 6 15
 a3 3 13 19 7
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I break the one-liner down into lines, to make it easier to read.

```
awk '{n[$1];for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[$1,i]+=$i}
    END{for(x in n){
        printf "%s ", x
        for(y=2;y<=NF;y++)printf "%s%s", a[x,y],(y==NF?ORS:FS)
        }
    }' file
```

this awk command should work with your 100 columns file.

test with your file:

```
kent$  cat f
a1 1   1   2   2
a2 2   5   3   7
a2 2   3   3   8
a3 1   4   6   1
a3 1   7   9   4
a3 1   2   4   2

kent$  awk '{n[$1];for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[$1,i]+=$i}END{for(x in n){printf "%s ", x;for(y=2;y<=NF;y++)printf "%s%s", a[x,y],(y==NF?ORS:OFS)}}' f
a1 1 1 2 2
a2 4 8 6 15
a3 3 13 19 7
```

Comment: `printf y==NF?"%s":"%s ",a[x,y]` will cause a syntax error with some awks (BSD awk on OSX maybe?). Parenthesising the ternary expression should resolve it: `printf (y==NF?"%s":"%s "),a[x,y]` though I'm a little surprised that works as I think I've seen syntax errors before trying to use ternary expressions before the first comma in a printf so for that reason and IMHO clarity I'd tend to write it as `printf "%s%s", a[x,y], (y==NF?ORS:OFS)` and then not have a separate `print ""` after the loop.

Comment: @EdMorton the `%s%s` is wise way! thank you.. I can always learn things from your comments/answers

Comment: @Kent could you please edit your answer, according to EdMorton's suggestion, so I can accept the answer? :)

Comment: also, this solution inserts empty line after each line

Comment: @user2904120 updated. there shouldn't be empty line in output. make sure you removed the `print ""`, since we have used `ORS`. check my edited answer.

Comment: can I skip this operation on table header, but print the original header in the end?

Answer (score 1):

If you care about order of output try this

```
$ cat file
a1 1   1   2   2
a2 2   5   3   7
a2 2   3   3   8
a3 1   4   6   1
a3 1   7   9   4
a3 1   2   4   2
```

**Awk Code :**

```
$ cat tester
awk 'FNR==NR{
              U[$1]                             # Array U with index being field1
              for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                # loop through columns thats is column2 to NF
              A[$1,i]+=$i                       # Array A holds sum of columns
              next                              # stop processing the current record and go on to the next record
            }
   ($1 in U){                                   # Here we read same file once again,if field1 is found in array U, then following statements
              for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
              s = s ? s OFS A[$1,i] : A[$1,i]   # I am writing sum to variable s since I want to use only one print statement, here you can use printf also
              print $1,s                        # print column1 and variable s
              delete U[$1]                      # We have done, so delete array element
              s = ""                            # reset variable s
            }' OFS='\t' file{,}                 # output field separator is tab you can set comma also
```

**Resulting**

```
$ bash tester
a1  1   1   2   2
a2  4   8   6   15
a3  3   13  19  7
```

If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS system`, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

**--edit--**

As requested in comment here is one liner, in above post for better reading purpose I had commented and it became several lines.

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{U[$1];for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)A[$1,i]+=$i;next}($1 in U){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s = s ? s OFS A[$1,i] : A[$1,i];print $1,s;delete U[$1];s = ""}' OFS='\t' file{,}
a1  1   1   2   2
a2  4   8   6   15
a3  3   13  19  7
```

Comment: is it possible to run it as one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

Using arrays of arrays in gnu awk version 4

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1][i]+=$i}
END{for (i in a) 
      { printf i FS;
        for (j in a[i]) printf a[i][j] FS 
        printf RS}
    }' file     

a1 1 1 2 2
a2 4 8 6 15
a3 3 13 19 7
```

Comment: +1 Maybe you should say that it needs Gnu Awk version 4?

Comment: looks nice but I cannot execute it

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, sure, I udpated it.

Comment: @user2904120 , what's the error message you get? is the version of gnu  awk v4?

Comment: this error:     
{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) >>>  a[$1][ <<<

Comment: @user2904120: check out the version of your `awk` using this `awk --v` on terminal as BMW already said its on `GNU awk 4`.

Comment: awk version 20070501 its on macbook (OSX 10.9.1)

Comment: it is `nawk` not `gawk` so it's not supporting.. you can download and install `gawk 4` and then try BMW's approach else use other two approach provided.