# calculate sum of similar lines with identical string

Tags: awk

How can I merge the lines that are identical in column 1 then get the sum of the values in column2 for those similar lines? I have tried different awk, but not sure how to get the sum correct.

```
__too_low_aQual 3
mir-10  5
Y_RNA   4
__too_low_aQual 0
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned   1
mir-8   2
mir-671 3
mir-671 16
mir-671 2
__too_low_aQual 4
SNORD91 3
__not_aligned   7
mir-10  104
__too_low_aQual 6
__no_feature    1
__too_low_aQual 0
SNORD58 6
__too_low_aQual 4
let-7   2
__not_aligned   0
__not_aligned   1
```

Comment: [sum-rows-based-on-unique-columns-awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785266/sum-rows-based-on-unique-columns-awk)

Comment: Show us what you tried. We will tell you where it's wrong

Comment: Thanks @JoseRicardoBustosM.

Comment: awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}'